# how to INSERT but IGNORE same date tag with pymssql python

Tags: sql, python-2.7, pymssql

I am having trouble ignoring a duplicate 'date' values when I am importing data

```
import pymssql
import datetime as dt

server = 'xx'
user = 'xx'
password = 'xx'
db = 'xx'
conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, db, as_dict=True)

cur = conn.cursor()
Table_create = 'CREATE TABLE table1 (t_date date, price FLOAT)'
cur.execute(Table_create)

today = str(dt.datetime.now().date())
yesterday = str(dt.datetime.now().date() - dt.timedelta(days=1))
nextday = str(dt.datetime.now().date() + dt.timedelta(days=1))
cur.executemany("INSERT  INTO table1(t_date, price) VALUES(%s,%d)", [(today, 100), (yesterday, 200)])
conn.commit()
```

I am getting

```
In[78]: x
Out[78]: 
[{u'price': 100.0, u't_date': u'2016-09-25'},
 {u'price': 200.0, u't_date': u'2016-09-24'}]
```

I want to ignore a same date record if I try to insert it again such has:

```
cur.executemany("INSERT  INTO table1(t_date, price) VALUES(%s,%d)", [(today, 100), (nextday, 200)])
conn.commit()
```

but I get duplicate such has:

```
In[80]: x
Out[80]: 
[{u'price': 100.0, u't_date': u'2016-09-25'},
 {u'price': 200.0, u't_date': u'2016-09-24'},
 {u'price': 100.0, u't_date': u'2016-09-25'},
 {u'price': 200.0, u't_date': u'2016-09-26'}]
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Make the column/s unique.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks! only problem is that it will cancel the whole import. I would appreciate something like a INNER JOIN but using the call 'VALUES' like I am doing in the example, As you probably guess I am not the best SQL guy out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options, you can make date your primary key, then on any duplicate entries just update the *price* using [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/):

```
Table_create = '''CREATE TABLE table1 (t_date date PRIMARY KEY, price FLOAT )'''
cur.execute(Table_create)

today = str(dt.datetime.now().date())
yesterday = str(dt.datetime.now().date() - dt.timedelta(days=1))
nextday = str(dt.datetime.now().date() + dt.timedelta(days=1))
cur.executemany("INSERT  INTO table1(t_date, price) VALUES(%s, %s) on DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE price=price",([(today, 100), (yesterday, 200)]))
```

That would only update the price if you happened to get a different/new price for an existing row or do an insert for a new date

You could also just IGNORE any duplicates:

```
"INSERT INSERT IGNORE INTO table1(t_date, price) VALUES(%s, %s)"
```

But IGNORE will ignore more than an `IntegrityError` based on the duplicate entry so I would personally prefer the former.

Another option if you wanted to have an auto_increment id and to use both t_date and price or just the t_date would be to create a [UNIQUE CONSTRAINT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

```
  Table_create = '''CREATE TABLE table1 (
                            ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                            t_date date,
                            price FLOAT,
                            CONSTRAINT no_dupes UNIQUE  (t_date, price))''' # CONSTRAINT no_dupes UNIQUE (t_date) for just the t_date
cur.execute(Table_create)
```

The same logic would apply when inserting.